# How to correctly use pointers in my c program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I turned in this code for my assignment to my teacher thinking I had completed his request that we use pointer techniques for writing our hangman assignment. He gave it back and said I used array techniques and not pointer techniques. I have struggled with learning pointers and arrays, so I am a bit confused how to fix where he said I went wrong.

These are the parts of my program he marked were array techniques and not pointer techniques:

```
*(q + i) = '*';

if (ch[0] == *(p + i))

*(q + i) = ch[0];
```

My full program code is below (can anyone help me understand how a proper pointer technique can be implemented, I clearly don't get it - THANKS in advance):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void Instructions();
void PlayGame();
void PrintToLog(char *word);

int main()
{

Instructions();
PlayGame();

return 0;
getchar();
}

void Instructions()
{
printf("This is a game of hangman. Attempt to guess secret word\n");
printf("by entering a letter from a to z. The game is over once you\n");
printf("have entered 8 incorrect guesses.\n\n");
}

void PlayGame()
{
char word[] = { "hello" };
char guessed[20];
int i, incorrect_count, found;
char ch[2];
char *p, *q;

p = &word;
q = &guessed;
strcpy(guessed, word);

PrintToLog(word);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(guessed); i++)
{
    *(q + i) = '*';
}
incorrect_count = 0;

while (incorrect_count < 8 && strcmp(guessed, word) != 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(guessed); i++)
        printf("%c ", guessed[i]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter your guess:");
        gets(ch);
        found = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        if (ch[0] == *(p + i))
        {
            *(q + i) = ch[0];
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
        incorrect_count++;
}

if (incorrect_count < 8)
{
    printf("\nThe word is %s. You win!", word);
    getchar();
}
else
{
    printf("\nThe correct word is %s. You lose!", word);
    getchar();
}

return 0;
}

void PrintToLog(char *word)
{
FILE *pOutput;

pOutput = fopen("MyLogFile.txt", "w+");
if (!pOutput) return;
fprintf(pOutput, "Start of game\n");
fprintf(pOutput, "This is the word player is trying to guess: %s\n", word);

fclose(pOutput);
}
```

Comment: Your teacher is bad at explaining themselves. They probably meant for you to modify the pointer itself. I.e: `p += i;` or `++p; // i times`.

Comment: I am not sure but I think your teacher is trying to say change like this `*(q + i) -> q[i]`.

Comment: replace  `ch[0]` as `*ch`, so that it becomes pointer way

Comment: Stop learning from the teacher.

Comment: Is it the same teacher that taught you to use `gets`? When you have this working and up & running, I recommend that you indent & format it correctly (needless to say) and then post the whole of it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `p = &word;` and `q = &guessed;` are incorrect; remove the `&` in both cases. `word` and `guessed` are arrays containing values of type `char`, which "decay" to pointers to their first items in most cases.

As an example of array decay, consider `guessed`:

```
Expression     Type
===========    ========
 guessed       char[20]
 guessed[0]    char
&guessed[0]    char *
```

- `guessed` has type `char[20]`, or "array of 20 `char` values".
- `guessed[0]` has type `char` and is the same as `*(guessed + 0)`, i.e. 0 `char`s from the beginning of the array (which is the first item in the array).
- `&guessed[0]` has type `char *` and is the same as `&*(guessed + 0)`. Since `&` and `*` are inverse operations, they cancel each other out, resulting in `&guessed[0]` being the same as `guessed + 0`—or just `guessed`. The only difference between `guessed` and `&guessed[0]` is the type because the `[0]` indexing operation happens before the `&`, causing the types to differ. Array decay effectively makes `guessed` the same as `&guessed[0]` in the context of your assignment to `q`, so you can write either one.

The exceptions where an array variable `guessed` will not behave the same as `&guessed[0]` are:

- `sizeof(guessed)`: gets the size of the entire array
- `&guessed`: gets a pointer to the array, with type `char (*)[20]`—pointer to array of 20 `char` values

As for your teacher's instructions, you probably need to modify the `p` and `q` pointers themselves rather than use `*(x + i)`, which is the same as `x[i]`.

For example:

```
q = guessed;
/* lines skipped */
for (i = 0; i < strlen(guessed); i++)
{
    *(q + i) = '*';
}
```

becomes:

```
/* lines skipped */
for (q = guessed; *q != 0; q++)
{
    *q = '*';
}
```

Similarly:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
    if (ch[0] == *(p + i))
    {
        *(q + i) = ch[0];
        found = 1;
    }
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
for (p = word, q = guessed; *p != 0; p++, q++)
{
    if (ch[0] == *p)
    {
        *q = ch[0];
        found = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate that explanation and input. That helped me understand it better. I was have had a hard time with this assignment but came out with a working program that I was proud until I got it back today from the teacher. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Original:

```
    *(q + i) = '*';
    if (ch[0] == *(p + i))
    *(q + i) = ch[0];
```

Becomes:

```
    q[i] = '*';
    if (ch[0] == p[i]))
    q[i] = ch[0];
```

A pointer is the base address, you can index it just like an array and the compiler will work out the offset according to the type declaration of the pointer.

q = base address of your data, [i] indexes from the base address.

I think I've interpreted your question wrong if you wanted to convert all the array references to pointers then:

Original:

```
    *(q + i) = '*';
    if (ch[0] == *(p + i))
    *(q + i) = ch[0];
```

Becomes:

```
    *(q + i) = '*';
    if (*ch == *(p + i)))
    *(q + i) = *ch;
```

I can't quite see the point that is trying to be made, in C there is no difference in pointers and arrays they are the same and you can access them either way.

Lets recode your loop:

```
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        if (ch[0] == *(p + i))
        {
            *(q + i) = ch[0];
            found = 1;
        }
    }
```

Becomes:

```
    for( p=word; *p!='\0'; p++ ) {
        if ( *ch == *p ) {
            *p = *ch;
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now you said something you didn't mean *in C there is no difference in pointers and arrays they are the same and you can access them either way.* Take as an example `sizeof(arr)` and `sizeof(pointer_to_array)`.

Comment: @coderredoc, no I meant what I said, an array can be accessed in exactly the same way as a pointer and vice versa.

Comment: @coderredoc, sizeof(ptr) gives 4 bytes on a 32bit system sizeof(array) if its the base address will give the same, if you want the size of the array then sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]).

Comment: @SPlatten Thanks! The main parts the teacher circled and said were array techniques instead of pointer techniques (we were supposed to make sure we used pointer techniques in the assignment) was *(q + i)  &  *(p + i)  &  *(q + i)  he specifically circled only those, but didn't the additional portions like the = ch[ 0 ]. So he specifically thinks those stated above were not pointers but array techniques and therefore my program did not meet the assignment requirements. Does changing them to q[ i ] and p[ i ] in my code make those pointer techniques? That's what I need to fix.

Comment: @c_languagewannabe, no, I think the terminology is not really appropriate.  Arrays and Pointers in C are the same thing, the notation of using [] to access a pointer enables the compiler to work out that offset, there is no difference in writing q[I] to *(q + I), the thing to note is the '*' which means the contents of the location.

Comment: *sizeof(ptr) gives 4 bytes on a 32bit system sizeof(array) if its the base address will give the same* - check once using a c compiler. Here `array` is declared as `int array[100]`.